# is there a way to import module A in another module B without making A a library module? in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am new to android. i am creating application that has three modules: message, monitorPhone and application. they depend on each other. message and monitorPhone depend on database module as it contains the database. now monitorPhone also depends on message to send message. Also message module depends on monitorPhone to activate a features.
i tried changing the module into library module. it works when monitorPhone and message module depend on database module which i have changed into library module. but message cannot be imported into monitorPhone. by changing both into library module i get error that "circular dependency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such luxury given to have this. 
What you can do is ; you can create all three as library and have one who inherit all on the top.
Thus avoiding circular dependency.
Android wont let you go ahead with circular dependency. :)